# Winforms switching between forms

Tags: winforms

I'm using winforms now.
I have the main form "form1" and I have a button that opens form2.
When I open form2 I would like for form1 to disappear. When the user click the x button on form2 I would like for it to close and go back to form1. I wouldn't like to use modal windows.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var frm = new Form2();
        frm.Location = this.Location;
        frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        frm.FormClosing += delegate { this.Show(); };
        frm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Nice one, I was using owner property up till this point but this would do it and actually much easier.

Answer (score 2):

In order **not to change Form's Properties**, simply **use** the `ShowDialog()` method in `Form1.cs` code to open `Form2`. That will deactivate `Form1`:

```
void OpenSecondForm()
{
  Form form2 = new Form();
  form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I think there is a typo.  sb Form form2 = new form2();

Comment: Pat is right, so anyone using this example should bear that in mind.